# OpenGL Texture Renders black eventhough its data is not null

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl

I have written a working 2D Batch Renderer in LWJGL OpenGL that works with colours. When I added Texture support to it, The Quad Rendered is always black. The data is read by STBImage just fine. But it still renders black.
Here's the shaders: Vertex:
Fragment:

```c
#version 450 core

in vec4 v_Colour;
in vec2 v_TexCoord;
in float v_TexIndex;

uniform sampler2D u_TextureSlots[16];

void main() {
    int index = int(v_TexIndex);
    gl_FragColor = texture(u_TextureSlots[index], v_TexCoord) * v_Colour;
}
```

The Renderer's Submit method

```
public static void Submit(Texture texture, Rect drawRect, Rect uvRect, Vector4f colour) {
    if (hasRoom) {
        texture.BindSlot(textureIndex + 1);
        int index = spriteCount++;
        int offset = index * 6 * VERTEX_COUNT;
        StoreData(offset, textureIndex++, drawRect, uvRect, colour);
        if (textureIndex >= 16) hasRoom = false;
        if (spriteCount >= maxBatchSize) hasRoom = false;
    }
}
private static void StoreData(int offset, int textureIndex, Rect drawRect, Rect uvRect, Vector4f colour) {
    float x1 = drawRect.x;
    float y1 = drawRect.y;
    float x2 = drawRect.x + drawRect.width;
    float y2 = drawRect.y + drawRect.height;
    float u1 = uvRect.x;
    float v1 = uvRect.y;
    float u2 = uvRect.x + uvRect.width;
    float v2 = uvRect.y + uvRect.height;
    for (int vertex = 0; vertex < 6; vertex++) {
        int currentIndex = offset + vertex * VERTEX_COUNT;
        float x = vertex == 0 || vertex == 3 || vertex == 5 ? x1 : x2;
        float y = vertex == 0 || vertex == 3 || vertex == 1 ? y1 : y2;
        float u = x == x1 ? u1 : u2;
        float v = y == y1 ? v1 : v2;
        vertices[currentIndex] = x;
        vertices[currentIndex + 1] = y;
        vertices[currentIndex + 2] = u;
        vertices[currentIndex + 3] = v;
        vertices[currentIndex + 4] = colour.x;
        vertices[currentIndex + 5] = colour.y;
        vertices[currentIndex + 6] = colour.z;
        vertices[currentIndex + 7] = colour.w;
        vertices[currentIndex + 8] = textureIndex;
    }
}
```

Texture:

```
public Texture(String filepath) {
        IntBuffer width = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
        IntBuffer height = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
        IntBuffer channels = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);

        ByteBuffer data = STBImage.stbi_load(filepath, width, height, channels, 0);
        m_Width = width.get();
        m_Height = height.get();
        m_Channels = channels.get();

        m_RendererID = glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererID);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, m_Width, m_Height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glTextureParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTextureParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        assert data != null : "Image " + filepath + " doesn't exist";
        STBImage.stbi_image_free(data);
    }
```

Comment: I edited the Question to include Texture

Comment: Please note that `u_TextureSlots[index]` is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means that it may work, but the specification does not guarantee that it will work. The behavior will be different on various hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of the fragment shader is undefined, because of:

```c
int index = int(v_TexIndex);
... u_TextureSlots[index]...;
```

`u_TextureSlots` is an array of samplers and `v_TexIndex` is a fragment shader input, thus `index` is not a [Dynamically uniform expression](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Dynamically_uniform_expression).
Note, undefined behavior means that it may work, but the specification does not guarantee that it will work. The behavior will be different on various hardware.

See GLSL version 4.60 (most recent) (from [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 4.1.7. Opaque Types](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#opaque-types)):
(Of course this rule applies to GLSL version 4.50, too)

> When aggregated into arrays within a shader, these types can only be indexed with a dynamically uniform expression, or texture lookup will result in undefined values.

---

I recommend to use `sampler2DArray` (see [Sampler](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL))) rather than an array of `sampler2D`.
When you use a `sampler2DArray`, then you don't need any indexing at all, because the "index" is encoded in the 3rd component of the texture coordinate at texture lookup (see [Texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL))).

---

Furthermore, either specify the texture target and use [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml)

```java
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

or the texture object and use [`glTextureParameteri`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml)

```java
glTextureParameteri(m_RendererID, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTextureParameteri(m_RendererID, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```